# Xcode error "Can't install application ... [appname].app requires the " z" capability which is not supported by [devicename]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working on a Wenderlich tutorial and got a new error message today. . I haven't seen this one yet and can't seem to find any answers via regular searches.

When trying to build and run on a device (iPhone 6+, iPhone 5, or iPad Mini running 9.1), I get the error that:

> "Can't install application ... [appname].app requires the " z" capability which is not supported by [devicename]."

What is the " z" capability, and how do I add this to the devices?

Added detail: The app is called Store Search app, and what it does is send search queries to the iTunes store. The error message really does say '" z" capability', with a leading space before the letter 'z'.

Comment: Note that the 6+ and Mini 4 are new devices that I have never built and run on. The iPhone 5 was working until today.

Comment: Furthermore, I reverted the code to the last known good state (where it definitely was able to install and run on the iPhone 5), and I am still seeing this error.

Comment: Does the message really say the "z" capability or is that some obfuscation you added to the question?

Comment: Provide more information. What is your app's functionality what are the device capabilities you are using ?

Answer (score 15):

Try checking Required device capabilities in your project info.plist

[image: Required device capabilities]

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, I had a typo. I diffed the info.plist file with one that was included with the tutorial and somehow a " z" worked its way into the Required device characteristics section... thanks for making me dig a little deeper!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Xcode 8, on your YourProjectName.xcodeproj, select your TARGET, then on Info tab, remove the gps item from the required device capability list.

[image]