# Can't install application error while installing in device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.2

> XXXXXX.app cannot be installed on [DEVICE NAME] XXXXX.app requires the “” capability which is not supported by [DEVICE NAME

I got this error while try to install in device, any one ever faced same situation ? 
I am using Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to info.plist and delete `required device capabilities` or add all neccessary architectures like `arm7` and `arm64` or else which your device required.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: arm7 and arm64 are not capabilities but architectures and are inside the "Build Settings" tab, not the "Capabilities"

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot : Used wrong word!! Updated it. thanks for suggestion. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to Add arm7 and arm64 to your `Required device capabilities` under the .plist file.
It is require to run your app on Your Device.
It's require to support the processor of your device.
Simulator doesn't contain any processor So it will run your application but Device can not.

Comment: i have to add arm7 and arm 64 both ?

Comment: Arm7 is for A6 processors and arm64 is for A7 processors so its based on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

In your application capabilities (.plist file in `Required device capabilities`), you have set to use one that is not available on the device you are using.

If you give more details about the device / OS version, I might be able to give you a more detailled answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check your .plist file in "required device capabilities". Maybe you have an item that is not properly entered and Xcode is detecting it as an actual capability to have.

Answer (score 2):

Check your info plist's Required Device Capabilities. Probably you have a typo there.

Answer (score 2):

Check you info.plist file for `Required device capabilities` typo mistakes.

refer this link for more detail: [Xcode error "Can't install application ... [appname].app requires the " z" capability which is not supported by [devicename]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272690/xcode-error-cant-install-application-appname-app-requires-the-z-capab)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Scheme from the scheme setting and add it once again
it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I used `connect via Network`. I removed iPhone from connected devices and connected again

Answer (score 0):

Open your info.plist and delete the arm64 from "Required device capabilities" and it will work.